# LVM cache and TRIM

Tags: linux, lvm, cache, ssd, trim

I have set up LVM to cache a logical volume (located on an HDD) on a partition of an SSD (in writeback mode if this matters). As far as I can tell, this works correctly and the cache uses all available space.

Now, I am wondering whether this setup issues TRIM command to the SSD and whether issuing such commands is necessary (or reasonable) to extend the SSD's lifetime. I have added `discard` to the options in `/etc/fstab` for the cached logical volume's entry. However, I have no idea how this affects the cache partition nor do I have an idea on how to test whether TRIM commands are issued.

Comment: Why do you suspect trim is being issued?

Comment: @Nils The problem is rather that I suspect no TRIM commands are issued and that this might negatively affect the SSD's lifetime.

Answer (score -1):

To test it, simply use:

```
fstrim -v -a
```

This will trim all your SSD block devices (including cached volumes) and print out how much has been trimmed.